# How does facebook/css-tricks.com write their header?

Tags: header, fixed, absolute

For example,

On facebook, when the user resizes their browser after a width of 1000px; the header stays fixed,
but after resizing below that, the header becomes absolute instead.

Same goes to css-tricks.com, after an amount of resizing, the value changes..
how do they do that?

To what i have in mind so far,
they're using jquery or some window.height() value coding.

I've tried searching for quite a long time (like 1 week?, but i do not know what are the keywords to search for, the tutorial is bound to be on google somewhere!)

Thank you for taking your time reading my question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be doing something like in your jquery initializations

```
if($(window).height() > = 1000){
    $("#your_id").removeClass("yourOtherClass").addClass("yourNewClass");
} else {
    $("#your_id").removeClass("yourNewClass").addClass("yourOtherClass");
}
```

I have just live typed this so untested at the mo. Hope this helps

Comment: i will update you pretty soon. will be testing it and tell you if it works. :) thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the simplest method, in your stylesheet, or in the header of your page, define something like:

```
    .header {
    width : 100%;
    max-width : 1000px;
    }
```

Then to use it:

```
    <div class="header">This should span the entire page up to 1000 pixels</div>
```

Comment: hi! i know about that, but what i want to know is = when the user resizes their browser, the css changes value. like facebook, it has a fixed header, but if its too small, it goes back to absolute and stays on top instead... thanks for the reply tho :). hope you get to answer my question (here) :).

Comment: okay, yours is partially right :). it should be @media (max-width:setyourwidth-px) {css values} THANKS! my problem is now solved :)